# (Rails) AJAX list of elements create/destroy and blank states

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a list of records displayed as a fairly normal tabular fashion (using Rails, hence the Ruby syntax).  This is not a "Rails" question, per se, but general practice:

```
<div class="list" id="records">
  <% if @records.empty? %>
    <%= render "blank_state" %>
  <% else %>
    <% @records.each do |record| %>
      <%= link_to record.name, record_path(record), class: "list-item", id: record.id %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'm using AJAX (jQuery) to add/remove records to the list.

```
# create.js.erb
$("#records-blank-state").remove(); # In case first record
$("#records").append("<%=j render(partial: "record", locals: { record: @record }) %>");

# destroy.js.erb
$("#<%= @record.id %>").remove();
<% if Record.count.zero? %>
  $("#records").html("<%=j render(partial: "blank_state") %>");
<% end %>

# _blank_state.html.erb
<div class="blank-state" id="records-blank-state">
  There are no records
</div>
```

As you can see, I initially display the `blank_state` partial if there aren't any records, but when I use AJAX to add a record, I want to make sure the `blank_state` goes away.

I do the same when I remove records, just in reverse: If I just removed the last record, I need to make sure I put the `blank_state` partial back in place.

Is there a better way to do this besides checking the count whenever I create/destroy?

I was trying to see if there was a way I could just CSS to just leave the `blank_state` on the page all the time but only display it when the records list was empty, but haven't had success with that.

What's the standard solution to a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do in this case is create only one partial that handle the whole logic.

In your view :

```
<div class="list" id="records">
  <%= render "records", records: @records %>
</div>
```

In your partial :

```
<% if @records.empty? %>
  <div class="blank-state">There are no records</div>
<% else %>
  <% @records.each do |record| %>
    <%= link_to record.name, record_path(record), class: "list-item" %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

then in your js views you can do :

```
# create.js.erb
$("#records").html("<%= j render "records", records: @records %>");

# destroy.js.erb
$("#records").html("<%= j render "records", records: @records %>");
```

So you could even render the same view for both actions.

Hope it helps